# How do you setup remote accounts to a server?

Tags: login, users

How can I have an Ubuntu client login to an account in Ubuntu server and have all their files on the server? I only want to have Ubuntu installed on the client PC but since it has an SSD it has a very limited space.

Alternatively, it would be even better if the client could network boot an Ubuntu instance from the server but I don't know if that's possible since the Desktop is wireless so I'm assuming I can only have the client have Ubuntu installed in the SSD

I'm looking for a step by step solution on how to do all this

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Do you want to remotely access the Ubuntu server and remotely run commands? Do you want to setup the Ubuntu server as a file server for the Ubuntu client computer? How big is the SSD in the Ubuntu client? Have you setup anything or is this a hypothetical question?

Comment: It's simple. I want a client PC to login but gets the login information from the server and their files are stored on the server. The client doesn't store anything and is actually a user account in the server